# way/generators making an error when pushing to heroku

Tags: heroku, laravel-4, push, laravel-4.2

When i push my **laravel** project to **heroku** i get this error :

```
remote: Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Way\Generators\Generator
sServiceProvider' not found in /tmp/build_1b7967dd29bc3201a8569a7c9f1e9c87/vendo
r/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
```

I think maybe it's the way/generators package that is causing this.

Answer (score 0):

solved by self-updating composer and then deleting and re-installing the package